# How to generate data from multivariate generalized pareto distribution

Tags: python, r, matlab, regression, simulation

I need to generate multivariate heavy-tailed data using generalized Pareto distribution but I can't find an explicit function to do that. The data has to be correlated as it will be used later in estimation based on regression.

I can work with functions in R, Python, or Matlab. Please share the suggestion if you have an idea

Comment: You could use a copula. What are your requirements more exactly?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I basically need to generate heavily tailed data especially for the main variable say X_1(so having positive extreme value index) and 3 (Y_1,Y_2,_Y_3) other related covariates. how i can then use the coupla for that purpose?!

Comment: With a copula you specify the marginal distributions (Gaussian, Gamma, generalized Pareto, ... anything you want), and they are correlated. Google for "copula". Do you have some requirements on the dependence?